# TensorFlow Dataset: Shuffling file names VS shuffling data after loading

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have found a bunch of question about shuffling dataset but non of them imply why just shuffling file names does not suffice.
Following is the code for loading the dataset for an image segmentation task:

```
train_files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(self.training_path)
train_files = train_files.shuffle(buffer_size=15000)
train_dataset = train_files.map(self.parse_image)

# -- Train Dataset --#
dataset['train'] = dataset['train'].map(self.load_image_train, num_parallel_calls=2)
#dataset['train'] = dataset['train'].shuffle(buffer_size=15000) 
dataset['train'] = dataset['train'].batch(self.batch_size)
dataset['train'] = dataset['train'].prefetch(buffer_size=1)  # will prefetch 1 batch
```

The question is that does `dataset['train'] = dataset['train'].shuffle(buffer_size=15000)` is necessary for shuffling data cause I already shuffled the file names?

Comment: No it is not necessary.

Comment: I think it is different. In this way, data are just shuffled at the beginning and just once and the network will feed by the same pattern of data in each epoch. While shuffling loaded date, shuffles at the beginning of each epoch, so different patterns in each epoch. am I right?